# Netstat vs Get-NetTCPConnection+Get-NetUDPEndpoint

Tags: powershell

Trying to update an old CMD script we had running which ran Netstat -ano and counted the output to find the amount of ports in use. I've come across Get-NetTCPConnection and Get-NetUDPEndpoint but the combined output of these is always a little off what Netstat returns. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Example:

```
PS C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\Powershell> (netstat -ano).count
((Get-NetTCPConnection)+(Get-NetUDPEndpoint)).count
204
189
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Netstat does not show connections in a 'bound' state. While Get-NetTCPConnection does show bound connections. [Get-NetTCPConnection Command Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM8bY.jpg)

There is really nothing extra that Get-NetUDPEndpoint cmdlet will provide vs what you see in netstat.

Comment: If Netstat does not retrieve bound connections and the alternative ((Get-NetTCPConnection)+(Get-NetUDPEndpoint)) does, I would of thought that I should receive a higher count with the PS cmdlet however I am getting a higher count from Netstat.